# how to 3D rotate a 'a' tag?

Tags: html, css

How to rotate a `<a>` with css 3D rotate?i have tried with this.

```
transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
transform:perspective(300px) rotateY(360deg);
-webkit-transform:perspective(300px) rotateY(360deg); 
-moz-transform:perspective(300px) rotateY(360deg);
-ms-transform:perspective(300px) rotateY(360deg);
-o-transform:perspective(300px) rotateY(360deg);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give element display `block` or `inline-block` to make transforms happen.

```
.rotate {
    display: inline-block;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transform:perspective(300px) rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform:perspective(300px) rotateY(180deg); 
    -moz-transform:perspective(300px) rotateY(180deg);
    -ms-transform:perspective(300px) rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform:perspective(300px) rotateY(180deg);
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u5Kxj/)